# Ansible regex_search stdout not working, but works in regex101.com

Tags: regex, ansible

I've read a thousand of the Ansible regex_search questions on here and have not found a satisfying answer.

Here's the test playbook. `backup_stdout` is set identically to what I get from the backup utility:

```yaml
---

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    backup_stdout: |-
      Saving active configuration...
      /var/local/ucs/f5-apm-1625-081021.ucs is saved.
  tasks:
    - name: Get the backup name
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        backup_name: "{{ backup_stdout | regex_search(stdout_regex, multiline=True) }}"
      vars:
        stdout_regex: '"\/var.*ucs\b"gm'
      failed_when: backup_name == ''

    - debug:
        var: backup_name
```

I can't get the `regex_search` to produce a match. [Here's the same code on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HDV1IG/1/), which shows that it does match. I've tried the following:

- with/without the `multiline`
- with/without the trailing `'\\1'` in the expression
- with/without passing the result to the `| first` filter
- using `^\/var.*ucs` instead of the word boundary (also matches on regex101)

So far, no matter what I've tried, I can't get the Ansible to match. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for providing a runnable playbook in your question. I wish everyone would do that!

Comment: @larsks - absolutely! Anything to help with a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got some weird quoting in your regular expression that is causing problems.  Because you've written:

```
stdout_regex: '"\/var.*ucs\b"gm'
```

You're passing the literal value `"\/var.*ucs\b"gm` to `regex_search`. There are no quotes (nor is there a `gm`) in the content of `backup_stdout`, so this is never going to match.

I think you want:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    backup_stdout: |-
      Saving active configuration...
      /var/local/ucs/f5-apm-1625-081021.ucs is saved.
  tasks:
    - name: Get the backup name
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        backup_name: "{{ backup_stdout | regex_search(stdout_regex, multiline=True) }}"
      vars:
        stdout_regex: '/var.*ucs\b'
      failed_when: backup_name == ''

    - debug:
        var: backup_name
```

Which produces:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "backup_name": "/var/local/ucs/f5-apm-1625-081021.ucs"
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why that didn't work the first time; I _swear_ I tried that combination. I initially thought it was b/c you didn't escape the `/` in your response, but I used `'\/var.*ucs\b'` and it worked just as well! *facedesk* Thanks again!